# Why is "install" run twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm going through Micharl Hartl's well known Rails tutorial, and this piece is confusing me. Every time a new app is set up, these commands are run:

```
$ bundle install --without production
$ bundle update
$ bundle install
```

I don't really get why `install` is being run twice. What is the effect of these three commands run in this sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not have to run `bundle install` twice as `bundle update` will also install all of your gems (as well as updating them to their most current version). I have not read the tutorial you mentioned but perhaps the purpose of the second `install` is to install all of the gems, including those reserved for production.

Your second question, what is the effect of these three commands:

1. `bundle install --without production`

   - Inspect the gemfile, ignoring gems that are reserved for production
   - Resolve all dependencies
   - Install all gems and dependent gems
   - Save the exact version of each gem to Gemfile.lock
2. `bundle update`

   - Inspect the gemfile
   - Resolve all dependencies from scratch using the newest version of each gem and completely ignoring Gemfile.lock
   - Install all gems and dependent gems
   - Save the exact version of each gem to Gemfile.lock
3. `bundle install`

   - Because this is the first run of the production gems, inspect the gemfile and resolve dependencies of the production gems
   - Use Gemfile.lock for exact versions of all other gems to be installed
   - Install all gems and dependent gems
   - Save the exact version of each gem to Gemfile.lock

Hoped this helped, for more detailed info about the two commands check out [this](http://people.sju.edu/~bforoura/CSC620/CH14/RubyOnRails/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/man/bundle-install.ronn) and [this](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-update.1.html).

Comment: The only thing I'm not getting now is why you would run bundle install after running bundle update, if all its functionality is already contained in the latter.

Comment: I don't see any reason for it. Based on what I know (which admittedly is not a ton) running bundle install immediately after bundle update will have no effect. That said, it also wont damage anything so perhaps it is just an extra check to make sure everything is installed correctly.

Comment: So does skipping the first line `bundle install --without production` is unnecessary because you''d be running it on line 3 again?

Answer (score -1):

`$ bundle install --without production` prevents bundler from installing any of the production gems.  It also gets saved in your local repository and you don't have to run it more than once.  Any subsequent run of `bundle install` will include `--without production`.

`bundle install` installs only the missing gems from your Gemfile, while `bundle update` updates/installs every single gem to the latest version as specified in the GemFile..

Comment: But why run it twice?